# Civil Rights Data Collection: Calculating the likelihood of enrolling in an advanced math course taught by a certified math teacher

Tags: probability, dataset

This question relates to the [Civil Rights Data Collection 2015-16 dataset](https://www2.ed.gov/about/offices/list/ocr/docs/crdc-2015-16.html). I want to calculate the likelihood by ethnicity of enrolling in an advanced math course taught by a certified math teacher.

I have the following features available:

- Number of students by ethnicity enrolled at each school
- Number of students enrolled in advanced math by race at each school
- Number of advanced math classes offered at each school
- Number of advanced math classes taught by a certified math instructor
  at each school

I am not certain if there is a statistically sound way to get what I’m after. I don’t know the individual-level enrollment in each math class, so I’m hoping the likelihood of a student of a given ethnicity being enrolled in advanced math and taught by a certified instructor can be reasonably inferred from the fields above.